seeds do not result in a valid address javascript
async function ata() {
  const secretKey = Uint8Array.from(JSON.parse(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY));
  const keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey);
  const owner = new PublicKey(keypair.publicKey);
  console.log(owner);
  const tokenMint = new PublicKey(
    "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112"
  );
  const TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID = new PublicKey(
    "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"
  );
  const SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY = new PublicKey(SystemProgram.programId.toString());

  const keys = [
    { pubkey: owner, isSigner: true, isWritable: true },
    { pubkey: owner, isSigner: false, isWritable: true },
    { pubkey: tokenMint, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
    { pubkey: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
    { pubkey: ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
    { pubkey: SystemProgram.programId, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
    { pubkey: SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
  ];
  const instruction = new TransactionInstruction({
    keys,
    programId: ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    data: Buffer.from([]),
  });
  let transaction = new Transaction().add(instruction);
  let blockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash("finalized");

  transaction.feePayer = keypair.publicKey;
  transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
  const txid = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [
    keypair,
  ]);
  console.log(txid);
}
ata();


hello, what should  I change in code to avoid an error in javascript like this:
  logs: [
    'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Create',
    'Program log: Error: Associated address does not match seed derivation',
    'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 3542 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL failed: Provided seeds do not result in a valid address'
  ]
}
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Provided seeds do not result in a valid address
```?


I do not see you passing in the ATA at all in your function, you need to obtain the ATA and then pass it in.
import { getAssociatedTokenAddress, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID } from "@solana/spl-token";

  // Determine the correct Associated Token Account address
  const associatedTokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
    tokenMint,
    owner,
  );

  const keys = [
    { pubkey: owner, isSigner: true, isWritable: true },
    { pubkey: associatedTokenAccount, isSigner: false, isWritable: true },
    { pubkey: tokenMint, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
    { pubkey: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
    { pubkey: ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
    { pubkey: SystemProgram.programId, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
    { pubkey: SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
  ];

Now apart from that there is a much easier and cleaner process to create the instructions and that is utilizing createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction
import { createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction, getAssociatedTokenAddress, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID } from "@solana/spl-token";

  // Determine the correct Associated Token Account address
  const associatedTokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
    tokenMint,
    owner,
  );

  let ataTransaction = new Transaction()
    .add(
      createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
        owner,
        associatedTokenAccount,
        owner,
        tokenMint
      )
    );

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/functions/getAssociatedTokenAddress.html
https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/functions/createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction.html
